# Problems with indentation due to img, what should I do?

Tags: html, css

In my code i have a error with margins.Please, help me witn it!

`HTML5:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Plant Company</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="background">
                <img class="logo-image" src="assets/image/logo.png" alt="Plant Company">
                <img class="main-img" src="assets/image/main-img.png" alt="Tree">
                <div class="nav">
                    <nav class="navigation">
                        <ul class="nav-btn">
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="btn" href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`CSS`:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,500&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

.container {
    position: relative;
}

.background {
    background: #F7FFEC;
    width: 739px;
    height: 840px;
}

.logo-image {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 209px;
    z-index: 2;
    
}

.main-img {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 20px;
}

.nav {
    z-index: 3;
    justify-content: top left;
}

.nav.navigation {
    display: in
}


.btn {
    margin: 45px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Raleway;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-btn {
    margin-left: 836px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #418A1C;
    text-decoration: underline;

}
```

It's all code, but here all very need.Also sorry for my English, i'm practicing.
It turns out that the buttons are 130px from the top, but they should be 60, which I just did not do, nothing comes out...

The above is a description of my problem

I tried to swap the blocks, nothing changed, I tried to change the display and styles of everything, but nothing worked, everything was in vain

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.